# Fancy box is doing to the link directly

Tags: jquery, lightbox, fancybox

I have this js

```
$(".features_edit").fancybox({
    'width'             : '38%',
    'height'            : '40%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

my html

```
 <li><a href="http://somthing.com/side/48/features/553/edit" class="features_edit">Apples</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://somthing.com/side/48/features/554/edit" class="features_edit">Oranges</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://somthing.com/side/48/features/555/edit" class="features_edit">Pears</a></li>
```

but when i click on the link it goes to the location rather then the lightbox
any ideas

Ok here is more infomation

All the links are getting added my javascript so when i did this

```
$(".features_edit").click(function(){
  console.log("testing");
});
```

nothing happened so maybe i need some sort of live or something to make it work any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is linked below.
http://fancybox.net/howto

Here are some things to consider about Fancybox:

1. Requires a valid doctype
2. Requires jQuery and fancybox js files.
3. Requires fancybox css file.

Additionally, your $(selector).fancybox({... statement must be inside a $(document).read(function{... statement.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a more complete code sample?  Are you getting any javascript errors?  I've also seen this when not including the proper path to the fancybox plugin js files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling the $.fancybox after the document is ready.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".features_edit").fancybox({
    'width'             : '38%',
    'height'            : '40%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
});
});
```